# Clearing a P0507 on a Dodge Stratus

Tags: dodge, rpm, warning-light, air-intake, stratus

My 06 Dodge Stratus (4 cylender) is showing a P0507 off of the Torque app. My idle is sitting at near 1100 rpm versus the standard 800.

I read up on the code and started looking for a vaccum leak with a lenght of tubing and an unlit propane torch. Nothing showed up.

I started back looking at Torque and noticed my "fuel trim bank 1 sensor 2" is consistently at 99.2%

I tried reving the engine in both park and neutral and I start getting a noticible shimmy at about 3,500 rpm. I can't get it any higher. Just a few months ago I could easily make it to 4500.

At the same time it starts to shimmy the fuel trim bank 1 sensor 1 drops to exactly 0%.

Where should I next look for the underlying problem?

EDIT:

Thanks for the responses. I ended up cleaning the air intake valve, replacing the map filter (filthier then I would have expected), both of which helped with the idle significantly.

I started looking at the PVC valve and some *** had stuck its line to a mounting nub on the case. No vaccum leak since it was technically sealed up. Moved it back where it belongs and she is running better then new.

Thanks again for everones input here. Much appreciated when I cant trust the local shop.

I wil never going back to that Firestone again. Their courtesy inspection broke one sensor (literally snapped the tip off my intake air temperature sensor), caused a flat tire and triggered this error code. Plus I'm pretty sure they intentionally loosened one of my tie rod ends.

Comment: I'm wondering if you have a bad throttle position sensor, but that would be a SWAG. That would be a higher end thing though. You may try cleaning your Air Idle Control (AIC) valve and see if it helps your idle situation.

Comment: So, this isn't an answer (but I couldn't find a message button or anything on here), but I've been having the same problem on my 2005 Dodge Stratus. I noticed you said Firestone, and mine started after my visit yesterday there for an air filter replacement. Lo and behold, we both live in Kansas City, so I'm assuming we probably went to the same place (or they at least have the same shady practices throughout KC)! I was wondering if you could help me out a little bit further with how you fixed the problem, I know very little about the actual parts under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [P0507 code](http://www.obd-codes.com/p0507) refers to:

> A P0507 DTC trouble code may be caused by one or more of the following: A vacuum leak Leaking air intake after the throttle body EGR valve leaking vacuum A faulty positive crankcase ventilation (PCV) valve Damaged/failed/dirty throttle body Failed EVAP system Failed IAC (idle air controller) or faulty IAC circuit

Things to look for would be:

- A vacuum leak Leaking air intake after the throttle body
- EGR valve leaking vacuum
- A faulty positive crankcase ventilation (PCV) valve
- Damaged/failed/dirty throttle body
- Failed EVAP system
- Failed IAC (idle air controller) or  faulty IAC circuit

Since you already checked for vacuum leaks (with a method I do not suggest, btw ... using a fine mist water bottle will provide you with much the same results without the risk of fire), I'd move right down the list. I'd think the high idle may be caused by the IAC, which could easily be solved by a good careful cleaning. Carbon or varnish buildup around the IAC pintle/seat may be to blame, allowing extra air. Before you replace any parts outright, clean the ones listed thoroughly. Also, clear the code between each successive try to make sure you aren't reading an old code.

As for not being able to reach over 3500 rpm, this is probably a separate issue, which may or may not have been exacerbated by the P0507 code issue. I'd see if you can't get the P0507 code cleared and fixed and then move onto the other. It is much easier trying to diagnose and fix one issue at a time than trying to chase after two.